# Mysql, How to group a set of rows by using the max value of another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that might have one or more rows with the same value for the **key_property** column.

I want to build a query in MySql that returns a set where every value of **key_property** is represented for only one of its corresponding rows and **that it also receives a key_property filter** for a *like* sentence, chosen by the max value of another column (say, **event_id**).

How can I achieve that?

UPDATE:

Here's a sample of the non-filtered table:

```
+--------------+--------+----------+
| key_property | others | event_id |
+--------------+--------+----------+
|    abcd      | B      |     1    |
|    abcd      | A      |     2    |
|    defg      | C      |     3    |
|    abcd      | D      |     4    |
|    hijk      | f      |     4    |
+--------------+--------+----------+
```

When executing the query with the filter setted as 'd', the result data should look like this:

```
+--------------+--------+----------+
| key_property | others | event_id |
+--------------+--------+----------+
|    abcd      | D      |     4    |
|    defg      | C      |     3    |
+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: show a sample with data and result  ..

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab I have now, but it doesn't actually cover all my requirements. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: it seems to me that codemonkeyliketab's suggestion with an additional where condition `key_property like '%d%'` would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab WHERE (key_property,event_id) IN 
( SELECT key_property, MAX(event_id)
  FROM tab
  WHERE key_property like '%d%'
  GROUP BY key_property
)
```

Comment: @Daniel Calderon Mori this should work as expected, doesn't it?